# hide div while clicking on outside it in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to hide a div when i clicked on outside it, below is my div

```
<div ng-show="item.showLimit" class="set-limit">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.newConcLimit" />
    <div>
        <button type="button" ng-click="item.newConcLimit = 0;">No Limit</button>
        <button ng-disabled="!(item.newConcLimit >= 0)" type="button" ng-click="setConcLimit(item);">OK</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

in controller I'm  trying to set `item.showLimit = false` in window click function but it is not setting.

Comment: You should set $scope.item.showLimit = false; in click function.

Comment: this div is inside of ng-repeat? and please show me your window click function code.

Comment: yes it is in ng-repeat

Comment: my window click function is 
angular.element($window).on("click", function(event) {
   $scope.$parent.item.showLimit = false;
  });

Comment: use  angular.element($window).on("click", function(event) { $scope.item.showLimit = false; });

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
$(window).click(function(e){
    $scope.item.showLimit = false;
});
```

Make sure you are adding this too. Otherwise the div will hide if you click inside the division also.

```
$('.set-limit').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Nope it won't work because that div is inside of ng-repeat